# How to include multiple @SpringBootApplication by @Profile?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to define multiple `@SpringBootApplication` configurations that should load different packages. So that I can only load certain parts of the application, depending on the `-Dspring.profiles.active=` property.

Eg, the following `MyApp1` startup class should only auto load classes under `com.myapp.config1` subpackages:

```
package com.myapp.config1

@SpringBootApplication
@Profile("app1")
public class MyApp1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApp1.class, args);
  }
}
```

And another package aside:

```
package com.myapp.config2

@SpringBootApplication
@Profile("app2")
public class MyApp2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApp2.class, args);
  }
}
```

Problem: I cannot have multiple `main()` in multiple classes, as I lateron want to run my app with `mvn spring-boot:run`. How could this be solved?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load different packages depending on a profile you should instead define different configuration classes that are annotated with different `@ComponentScan` annotations.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("bar.foo")
@Profile("app1")
public class loadApp2 {

}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("foo.bar")
@Profile("app2")
public class loadApp1 {

}
```

This is actually the recommended way of setting up configuration and is called "slicing" and is documented in the [spring boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.user-configuration-and-slicing)

Comment: The docs are about unit test slicing, not a real application startup.

Comment: Why? Let's say I have an application the can process json data in two ways: 1) convert them to csv and store them on the disc. 2) import the aggregated csv into a database. The convert job could be triggered with a `spring.profiles.active=csv` every 2 minutes, while the database could could be triggered with `spring.profiles.active=mysql` only once a hour. It is totally valid then to not load the unnecessary classes for each job stage.

Comment: first of all, if its 2 different applications, then create 2 different applications. Don\t do something strange custom, not recommended as it will bite you in the ass. Like for instance now you need to do a custom solution to get it to work. Also, why not just write 1 application that supports BOTH things, instead of doing some weird switching.  As pointed out, you are doing a strange solution, and strange solutions will eventually bite you in the ass in the end. The answer i posted works, but from an enterprise perspective i would never approve such a solution.

Comment: why just not write an application that has support for both functionality? or create 2 applications? but no you are doing a strange custom solution which will just snowball into more strange custom solutions in the end. Read the recommended project setup for spring boot. If that doesn't work for you then maybe you should think about not using a framework.

Comment: That's what I'm for: write 1 application that supports both. Both both jobs should not run concurrently. One job like the csv job minutely, one job like the mysql job hourly. The csv job don't need a database connection wired up at startup, thus I still think it's valid to exclude like the db configuration classes (=profile mysql).

Comment: well right now you are writing 2 applications, instead run 1 normal application and setup 2 schedulers that run at different times and connect to the database, do what you want then disconnect. Don muck around with the main class and load different classes on startup. Load the entire application, and have 2 different scheduled jobs. I dont get it why complicate things?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, then you want to run different class based on profiles,  then you can have profile like below:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("abc")
@Profile("app1")
public class MyApp1 {
  //
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("xyz")
@Profile("app2")
public class MyApp2 {
  //
}
```

Now in your SpringBootapplication:

```
@SpringBootApplication
  public class SpringApp {
    
    @Autowired
    Environment env;
    
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (Arrays.asList(env.getActiveProfiles()).contains("app1"))
          SpringApplication.run(MyApp1.class, args);
       else 
         SpringApplication.run(MyApp2.class, args);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Why have you annotated the classes with `@Profile` and `@Configuration` and then in the main class you check what profile is set in the application.properties and then startup the class manually. If you are not using the built in spring scanning, why do you even then annotate the classes? there arre so many faulty things with this answer

Answer (score -1):

Could solve it as follows.

```
package com.myapp
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.myapp.config")
public class MyApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
  }
}
```

Which loads config:

```
package com.myapp.config

@Configuration
@Profile("app1")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.myapp.app1")
public class App1Config {
    //only load classes from app1 package
}

@Configuration
@Profile("app2")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.myapp.app2")
public class App2Config {
    //only load classes from app2 package
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could specify the main class in the spring boot plugin configuration. I am not sure if you are using gradle or maven... so cant tell you the exact config.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#goals-repackage-parameters-details-mainClass